# asp.net core api get null value from kotlin

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, asp.net-core-webapi

I created an API with ASP.net Core that works with postman well. But when I pass data with Kotlin and Retrofit, API get null values. All data send to server via Kotlin fine.
All models in Kotlin and in ASP.net Core are same.

This is my Retrofit class:

```
class ApiClient {
    companion object{
        var retrofit:Retrofit? = null
        var baseUrl = "http://10.0.2.2:5000/api/"
        fun getClient():Retrofit{
            if(retrofit == null){
                var okHttpClient = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                    .addInterceptor {
                        var oldRequest = it.request()
                        var newRequestBuilder = oldRequest.newBuilder()
                        if (Utils.myToken != null) {
                            newRequestBuilder.addHeader("token", Utils.myToken!!)
                        }
                        newRequestBuilder.addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                        newRequestBuilder.method(oldRequest.method, oldRequest.body)
                        return@addInterceptor it.proceed(newRequestBuilder.build())
                    }.build()
                retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .build()
            }
            return retrofit!!
        }
    }
}
```

This is Retrofit Interface Code:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("authentication/login")
fun login(
    @Field("username") username:String,
    @Field("password") password:String
):Call<Result>
```

This my Kotlin code:

```
loginViewModel.login(username,password).observe(viewLifecycleOwner,{
                    if(it.Status < 0){
                        Toast.makeText(context,it.Message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }else{
                        val manager = activity?.supportFragmentManager
                        loginViewModel.setToken(it.Message)
                        loginViewModel.setRoleId(it.Status)
                        Utils.createAnimation(activity?.findViewById(R.id.frm_mainActivity_mainLayout),Techniques.SlideInRight,700,0)
                        Utils.createFragment(manager!!,HomeFragment(),false)
                    }
                })
```

This is ASP.net Core API code:

```
[HttpPost("login")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Result>> Login(string username,string password){
    var user = await _repository.Login(username,password);
    Result result = new Result();
    if(user == null)
    {
        result.Status = -1;
        result.Message = "نام کاربری یا کلمه عبور اشتباه است";
        return NotFound(result);
    }
    else
    {
        result.Status = user.RoleId;
        result.Message = user.Token;
        return Ok(result);
    }
    
}
```

So why does API get null values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a DTO as login then pass that to Login function in ASP.net Core instead of username and password like this:

```
  public class Login
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

The login function in controller changes like this:

```
[HttpPost("login")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Result>> Login(Login login){
    var user = await _repository.Login(login.Username,login.Password);
    Result result = new Result();
    if(user == null)
    {
        result.Status = -1;
        result.Message = "نام کاربری یا کلمه عبور اشتباه است";
        return NotFound(result);
    }
    else
    {
        result.Status = user.RoleId;
        result.Message = user.Token;
        return Ok(result);
    }
    
}
```

Then in Kotlin should create a model like the Login DTO in ASP.net Core

```
class Login(var username:String,var password:String)
```

Now should change Retrofit interface and use @Body instead of @Field like this:

```
 @POST("authentication/login")
    fun login(@Body login: Login):Call<Result>
```

So should change all methods that call the login method, because now this method takes login model instead of username and password